# Find repeated elements in array list

Tags: java

The following code is suppose to  take a string for author and title to check if that exact book is in the array list if it is then it would return the number of copies in the array. So far it's only checking if the book is in the array list, but I was wondering if there is any IPA that I can use to find repeated elements in an array list

```
public class Book{
       private title;
       private author;
    }

public class Library {
        private ArrayList<Book>libraryBooks;
         public int checkNumCopies(String title,String author){
            int numBookCopies = 0;
            for(Book b:libraryBooks){
                if((b.equals(title))&& (b.equals(author))){
                    return "Book is in the library";    
                    }
                 else
                     return "Book is not in the library";
                }
            }
```

Comment: Instead of `return "Book is in the library";` add `numBookCopies++;` remove `else` block and return `numBookCopies` in the end.

Answer (score 1):

With proper implementation of equals and hashcode implementation in `Book`

```
class Book {

    private String author;
    private String title;

    //Getters and Setters
    //hashCode and equals impl
    //toString impl

}
```

this can be achieved using streams

```
    List<Book> books = Arrays.asList(new Book("book-1", "title-1"), new Book("book-2", "title-2"), new Book("book-3", "title-3"),
            new Book("book-1", "title-1"), new Book("book-2", "title-2"));
    Map<Book, Long> bookCount = books.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(b -> b, Collectors.counting()));
    System.out.println(bookCount);
```

output

```
{Book [author=book-3, title=title-3]=1, Book [author=book-2, title=title-2]=2, Book [author=book-1, title=title-1]=2}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the number of copies of a book, that would be:

```
public int checkNumCopies(String title, String author) {
    int numBookCopies = 0;
    for (Book b : libraryBooks) {
        if ((b.title.equals(title)) && (b.author.equals(author))) {
            numBookCopies++;
        }
    }
    return numBookCopies;
}
```

Otherwise, instead of sending title and author individually you can send a book object. That'd be better way :

```
public int checkNumCopies(Book book) {
    int numBookCopies = 0;
    for (Book b : libraryBooks) {
        if ((b.title.equals(book.title)) && (b.author.equals(book.author))) {
            numBookCopies++;
        }
    }
    return numBookCopies;
}
```

Since you have made the fields `private`, you need  to write getter methods for getting the values from the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Book` fields are missing types (I assume you wanted `String`s), and you have no accessor (or *getters*) for those fields. Also, I would probably override `equals` and use that. Something like,

```
public class Book {
    public Book(String title, String author) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
    }

    private String title;
    private String author;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj instanceof Book) {
            Book b = (Book) obj;
            return b.title.equals(title) && b.author.equals(author);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then to use it, I would do something like

```
private List<Book> libraryBooks = new ArrayList<>();

public int checkNumCopies(String title, String author) {
    Book toFind = new Book(title, author);
    int numBookCopies = 0;
    for (Book b : libraryBooks) {
        if (b.equals(toFind)) {
            numBookCopies++;
        }
    }
    return numBookCopies;
}
```

**or** in Java 8+, like

```
Book toFind = new Book(title, author);
return (int) libraryBooks.stream().filter(book -> book.equals(toFind)).count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could create an equals method on Book and then use a HashSet. Something like

```
public class Book{
   private title;
   private author;

   //implement hashcode

   public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (!(o instanceof Book)){ return false}
      Book that = Book.class.cast(o);
      // you may want to do a null check here
      return this.title.equals(that.title) && this.author.equals(that.author);
   }

}

 public class Library {
    private ArrayList<Book>libraryBooks;
     public int checkNumCopies(String title,String author){
        return libraryBooks.size() - new HashSet(libraryBooks).size()
     }
 }
```

Im not sure entirely on what you need (sorry cant quite understand the question) but hopefully this at least gives you some ideas.

note: I havent compiled this so please excuse any compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using java streams API

```
public class Library {

    private ArrayList<Book> libraryBooks;

    public long checkNumCopies(String title, String author) {

        return libraryBooks
            .stream()
            .filter(book -> book.getAuthor().equals(author) && book.getTitle().equals(title))
            .count();

    }
}
```

I presupposed that there are getter methods in Book class.